# in a loop, store the values of given matrix in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, store

I have the following code

```
clc
clear

fcm=65

for t = 0.1:0.01:28
    s = 0.2;
    Bcc = exp(s*(1-(28/t)^0.5));
    fcmt = fcm *Bcc
end
```

And I want to store the values of the given matrix in an array, how can I do this?

Comment: What is `i`, the "array" or the "matrix"? Please clarify.

Comment: sorry, could you please define the difference between array and matrix you mean?

Comment: sorry the i is a mistake I have edited and taken it out

Answer (score 0):

```
clc,clear all,close all

fcm = 65;
s = .2;
t = .1:.01:28;

Bcc = exp(s.*(1-(28./t).^0.5));
fcmt = fcm*Bcc;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Mustafa Nasser: you should think of upvoting my answer and accept it!